# C# Dynamically change notifyicon image in Tray

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have PPP Dialer program in **C#**. After successfull connection, it minimize to system tray  with icon.

How can I dynamically change notifyicon image in Tray according to the connection state?

**Example:**

If connection is idle: ICON-IMAGE-1
If connection is Connected: ICON-IMAGE-2
If connection is Disconnected: ICON-IMAGE-3

I have the triggers on events, just wanted to know how to change try icon according to the event.

Comment: possibly duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105307/changing-system-tray-icon-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NotifyIcon`

```
private NotifyIcon _nIcon;
```

I do it like this. I first initialize the notification in the app constructor.

```
System.IO.Stream iconStream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream( new Uri( "pack://application:,,,/;component/Resources/offline.ico" )).Stream;
_nIcon = new NotifyIcon();
_nIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

and then when your connection changes:

```
System.IO.Stream iconStream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/;component/Resources/online.ico")).Stream;
_nIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your time and reply. I finally made it by adding the icons/images in the project resources, then called it using `notifyIcon1.Icon = Resource1.icon_online;` & `notifyIcon1.Icon = Resource1.icon_offline;` in ras connection watcher. :)